# Get Angular cli build hash

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

Is there any way to get the angular cli's build hash and use it in the environments file?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm about to write some hacky shell script on deploy to work this out.

Comment: @MattTheNinja To be honest I found a way around this with a custom gulp script and then with service workers. Nowadays Angular supports service workers through cli which made it complete easy to leave the version update on them. Originally I wanted the hash to check the app version.

Comment: Did anyone find a way to do this? I am looking for a way to generate a hash same was as ng build --prod generates the hash to check the application version/file changes for auto updating.

Comment: @AhmedDolabi I have ended up using the angular service worker for managing my app versions. Angular service worker can be found in the later angular versions. The logic behind this is different from checking the cli hash. The angular service worker provides methods in  order to check for new versions.